# SQL-Time difference

Tags: sql

2 Tables with the below model:

```
Id: long unique; timestamp:long; price:double
```

The data in both tables are identical except timestamp.
Timestamp is given as `unix_time` in `ms`.

Question: how many pairs have a bigger time difference than 1000ms?

Comment: In general, you should mention the SQL dialect you're using in your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM Table1 t1 INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
WHERE 
    (t1.timestamp - t2.timestamp > 1000) or 
    (t2.timestamp - t1.timestamp > 1000)
```

Comment: @Rax, Tried your query. It showing desired result's. Thanks a ton !

Answer (score 0):

assuming the IDs are same for both tables and timestamp is the only different field

assume these are your tables

```
ID | timestamp | price
```

we will call them table1 and table2

```
select count(*) from table1 t1
 inner join table2 t2 on t1.ID=t2.ID
 where (t1.timestamp-t2.timestamp) > 1000
 or (t2.timestamp-t1.timestamp)>1000
```

Comment: @Saeros, I tried your query, But i dont require group by. I just need the count only and that too Id column is having unique right.. thank you for your answer!